# Is $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n\pi+(-1)^n\frac{\pi}{2}}=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

When I am trying to prove $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ has no limit at $x=0$, I came up with this problem.  Is $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n\pi+(-1)^n\frac{\pi}{2}}=0 \,\,?$$

My problem is there is $(-1)^n$ so I can't understand but I think it is convergence to $0$

Can someone help me to understand?

Comment: Forget π/2 and π just take 1/{2n+(-1)^n} what do you think what is its limit?now if n increases 2n increases more rapidly and after sometime (-1)^n will have no effect. You can write few terms of $2n+(-1)^n } and you'll see what I am trying to say.

Comment: $(-1)$ just flips from $-1$ to $1$ to $-1$.  So if $n$ is even you have $\frac 1{n\pi +\frac \pi 2}$ and if $n$ is odd you have $\frac 1{n\pi -\frac  \pi 2}$.  As both of these converge to $0$ (because as $n$ gets large the $\pm \frac \pi 2$ becomes negligible) then the whole sequence goes to $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We always have
$$\frac1{\pi(n+1/2)}\le\frac1{n\pi+(-1)^n\pi/2}\le\frac1{\pi(n-1/2)}$$
and so by the squeeze theorem the limit is $0$.

Comment: Thank you  for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Heuristically, $n\pi$ grows like $n$ to $\infty$, and the $(-1)^n\frac{\pi}{2}$ term is insignificant because it's just adding or subtracting a constant $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

More formally, you could use the squeeze theorem with $$(n-1)\pi\leq n\pi+(-1)^n\frac{\pi}{2}\leq (n+1)\pi.$$

Comment: Thank you  for your answer